# How do I connect storyboard to swiftui?

Tags: swift, storyboard, swiftui, nsresponder

How do I connect the storyboard to swiftUI? I have tried to go to the finder/editor/assistant but it takes me to 'NSResponder.h' Is this the right place to connect code and storyboard in a Mac OS application? If so where in said file? If not what do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to use storyboard and SwiftUI in same iOS Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56529488/is-there-any-way-to-use-storyboard-and-swiftui-in-same-ios-xcode-project)

Answer (score 1):

By creating subclass UIHostingController. This questions answer is provided in another question. Please check out this link.

[Is there any way to use storyboard and SwiftUI in same iOS Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56529488/is-there-any-way-to-use-storyboard-and-swiftui-in-same-ios-xcode-project)

Comment: I'm trying to create a Mac application. I created a subclass file of NSHosting View, I IBSegue'd to that file from my storyboard. It doesn't work.