# Neumorphism design using Swift storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, swiftui, uistoryboard

I have seen quite a few tutorials online referring to the use of **neumorphism** design. However it appears to be only limited to SwiftUI.

Therefore it leads me to two questions:

1) Is this design style possible using regular storyboards (without SwiftUI) on an existing UIView?

2) Failing question 1, is it possible to inject a SwiftUI element, if the majority of the project is configured using storyboards.

Thanks for help in advance,

James.

Answer (score 0):

For question number 1, there might be some third party libraries to help you create neumorphic elements. [Here is an example](https://github.com/hirokimu/EMTNeumorphicView).

For question number 2, refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58250271). It explains how you can embed a SwiftUI view controller in a storyboard.

Hopefully this helps!