# Is there any way to use storyboard and SwiftUI in same iOS Xcode project for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, watchos

As Swift 5 introduces the SwiftUI framework for creating the views, but I'm currently using the storyboard for UI design for Apple Watch.

So I just wanted to know the procedure to use Storyboard and Swift UI in same Apple Watch Application.

I saw this [Is there any way to use storyboard and SwiftUI in same iOS Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56529488/is-there-any-way-to-use-storyboard-and-swiftui-in-same-ios-xcode-project) but there is no UIViewController or UIHostingController on WatchOS

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WKHostingController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/wkhostingcontroller) is the WatchKit equivalent of `UIHostingController`.

If you use `WKHostingController`, you'll be able to use a SwiftUI view in a storyboard on watchOS.

Comment: hah perfect! thansk!